# Vaadin Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-security, vaadin8

I have been working from an example I found, here's the link to the Git repo:

https://github.com/basakpie/vaadin8-spring-security-sample

It works great, it's just what I need, except for one thing: I need Server Push.

Here's what I've done so far:

- added the Vaadin Push dependency
- added the following lines to the start of the MainUI.init() method:

  ```
  getPushConfiguration().setTransport(Transport.WEBSOCKET);
  getPushConfiguration().setPushMode(PushMode.AUTOMATIC);
  ```
- Added the following fields to the MainUI class:

  ```
  Label time = new Label();
  Timer timer;
  ```
- Added the following method to the MainUI class:

  ```
  private void updateTime() {
    access(() -> time.setValue(String.format("The server-side time is %s",  LocalTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss")))));
  }
  ```
- Finally, added the following to the end of the MainUI.init() method:

  ```
  timer = new Timer();
  timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
          updateTime();
      }
  }, 1000L, 1000L);
  ```

It mostly works. I am able to see the current system time updating every second. But when I hit refresh in the browser, the application just hangs with the vaadin loading spinner. There are no error messages.

I have tried the following alternatives:

Adding the method

```
public void attach() {
    getPushConfiguration().setTransport(Transport.WEBSOCKET);
    getPushConfiguration().setPushMode(PushMode.AUTOMATIC);
}
```

and removing the `getPushConfiguration` lines from `init()`

This solves the hanging problem, but the push does not work - no errors, just the time is not displayed at all.

I also tried adding a `@Push` annotation to `MainUI`. This results in the same behaviour as before - freezing on refresh.

How can I fix this? Any suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Try out the below procedure:

1. Add `@Push` to the MainUI.java file

   `@Push(transport = Transport.WEBSOCKET,value = PushMode.AUTOMATIC)`
2. Instead of :

   `getPushConfiguration().setTransport(Transport.WEBSOCKET);
   getPushConfiguration().setPushMode(PushMode.AUTOMATIC);`
3. Add `@PreDestroy` to exit the timer when you navigate from the mainUI

   `@PreDestroy
       void destroy() {
           timer.cancel();
       }`

Find the complete revised code [HERE](https://gist.github.com/cansoftinc/351452ee0e616d353519f147c4a961ba)

https://gist.github.com/cansoftinc/351452ee0e616d353519f147c4a961ba

Comment: thanks for the tip. Unfortunately I see the same behaviour :(

Answer (score 0):

I Had exactly the same problem and my solution to this was to implement the [vaadin servlet](https://github.com/peholmst/SpringSecurityDemo/blob/master/hybrid-security/src/main/java/org/vaadin/peholmst/samples/springsecurity/hybrid/CustomServlet.java). Check [this](https://vaadin.com/blog/filter-based-spring-security-in-vaadin-applications) for more information.